# Use Backpack's Admin CRUD also for normal user

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-backpack, user-management

Is it possible to use Backpack's Admin CRUDs also for the normal user (obviously with limited functionality)?

For example, with the route website.com/admin I can access Backpack's Admin panel, but what if I want to give the normal user the possibility to use the tools that Backpack offers (same views, same methods) but for example without the possibility of adding/updating/removing other users but just to visualize them? And maybe in another route different from website.com/admin.

Or maybe using the same components, but visualizing in a different way (limited actions for the normal user) with a middleware that checks if the user is admin or not

Answer (score 0):

You should use the permission manager package. You decide which role with the permissions you want and can condition access as you want ;)

[Here](https://github.com/Laravel-Backpack/PermissionManager)

Comment: Oh I'm glad there is a way to do it. Could you be more specific on what I should do? I consider myself a beginner so I don't really know where to put my hands with the thing you said

Comment: Can I use this if I already created the role's Model, migration, the field in the users table...?